# Angular5 Universal lazy loading on firebase hosting and seo

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular5, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

Does anyone know howto get lazyloading on firebase hosting working?
It all works but when I view the source code of my site, I only see the router-outlet and not the text and so on. I've added the code below to my index.js inside the functions folder:

```
extraProviders: [
  provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
]
```

My app.server.module file looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
AppModule,
ServerModule
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

But when I use firebase deploy in my console, it has deployed succesfully. However when I visit my site after that, I get an error and a blank page.

So if anyone can point me to the right direction, that would be awesome !

Comment: Hi. have you figured out a solution yet? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Hi Phil. I currently switched to rendertron. The cool thing about that is that you don't need server side rendering at all. take a look at this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. May I ask if you had any trouble with Lazy-Loaded Angular-Modules in Rendertron?

Comment: Hi Phil, Rendertron does not have any problems with Lazy loaded modules. As long as your page load is under 10 seconds I believe.

Comment: that sounds awesome, thank you. Actually right now I am looking into Rendertron already. Did you use this https://github.com/AngularFirebase/E66-Angular-SEO-Rendertron as a reference? Do you have any idea why this project uses a native service-worker instead of the proxy/adapter from the Angular-framework?

Comment: Yes I've used that reference. I'm not sure what you mean with the native service worker. But the only drawback I found is that it uses docker and now my rendertron instance is hosted in google cloud platform which cost some extra money. I've contacted a regular hosting provider, but they where not able to run this because it would conflict with their server setup. Other then that, it's a great solution.

Comment: service workers are a browser-native thing, nothing from Angular exclusively. You can use them with React etc too, the way it's used in that reference project. But you also have the @angular/service-worker package, which is in the package.json-dependencies, but not activated (in angular-cli.json you see "serviceWorker": false). I was wondering why the tutorial doesn't go with the official Angular solution. By the way, you can host functions also on firebase-functions, aws-lambda and any other serverless hoster. with firebase you have some free limit, the others I did not check yet

Comment: HI Phil, I didn't know about service workers, so I've learned something new today ;-) It looks very promissing but I don't have the time to dive into that right now. I know about the firebase-functions and the free limit. But I'm struggeling on what to tell my clients about the costs when they go above this limit. The rendertron, as in the reference described, requires to use the Blaze plan of firebase.

Comment: Hi. Are you sure about that? I got the app running for me without a blaze plan. After all, the firebase-function is just forwarding the request to either firebase hosting (with your non-prerendered app) or to a public server running rendertron, which renders the site in advance. but both functions and hosting are free to use with some limitations

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had to activate the blaze plan for the rendertron instance, which is hosted on the google cloud platform. This is what the tutorial also showed. If you know another place to host the rendertron part, I would love to hear that. ;-)

Comment: but did you go with the full production solution straight away or have you tried out the "Rendertron Demo" mentioned in the tutorial before? I would only pay money and deploy an own solution if that really doesnt scale good enough for a simple blog.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I've tried the demo and now I'm using my own. Currently I have a try-out plan Google offers. You'll get $300 to play around on google platform. So, right now it doesn't cost me anything. But maybe it's a good idea to switch to the demo...

Answer (score -1):

It may be because you are missing the `ModuleMapLoaderModule` module in your imports

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader'

@NgModule({
imports: [
AppModule,
ServerModule,
ModuleMapLoaderModule
],
```

It seems to be needed for lazy loaded routes:

> The ModuleMapLoaderModule is a server-side module that allows lazy-loading of routes.

https://angular.io/guide/universal#app-server-module

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your help. I've allready added that to my app.server.module. This is how my index.js looks like in the functions folder:`

app.get('**', function (req, res) {
    renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
        url: req.path,
        document: index,
        extraProviders: [
          provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
      ]

    }).then(html => res.status(200).send(html));
});` Now I'm getting this error when I open my website: Error 503 first byte timeout

Comment: I can't really tell. You need to do some debugging to see where it fails. Does the request reach your node.js handler? Does it reach the module bootstrap? Does it reach the AppComponent? And so on

Comment: For your information, I'm deploying this to firebase hosting. So I have no idea how to test it. The deployment is running succesfully but somehow it just breaks. When I deploy it without the extraProviders it works.