# Angular Universal Firebase: no provider for InjectionToken MODULE_MAP

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal

Why do I get

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[NgModuleFactoryLoader -> InjectionToken MODULE_MAP]: 

  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgModuleFactoryLoader -> InjectionToken MODULE_MAP]: 

    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MODULE_MAP!
```

when trying to deploy with firebase?

I do use

```
extraProviders: [

  provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)

]
```

and in my app-server.module I do import ModuleMapLoaderModule (btw I tried importing ServerModule and AppModule in a different order, I was told it might be the problem, but it didnt work):

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [

    ServerModule,

    AppModule,

    ModuleMapLoaderModule,

  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})

export class AppServerModule { }
```

The main.bundle.js contains this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

var app_server_module_ngfactory_1 = __webpack_require__("./src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js");

exports.AppServerModuleNgFactory = app_server_module_ngfactory_1.AppServerModuleNgFactory;

var __lazy_0__ = __webpack_require__("./src/app/features/blog/blog.module.ngfactory.js");

var app_server_module_1 = __webpack_require__("./src/app/app.server.module.ts");

exports.AppServerModule = app_server_module_1.AppServerModule;

exports.LAZY_MODULE_MAP = { "app/features/blog/blog.module#BlogModule": __lazy_0__.BlogModuleNgFactory };
```

`main.bundle.js` does get imported in the firebase script correctly, because if I change some letters in the `require(...)`, I get an error that the file is not known. So what is wrong with the `LAZY_MODULE_MAP`?  it looks like a string-route-to-factory map/js-object and it gets exported. so why does it not get resolved by `provideModuleMap` correctly? The `BlogModule` has only a declaration of a Hello-World-Stub component.

Btw, there is a similar question here but with no replies: [Angular5 Universal lazy loading on firebase hosting and seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038948/angular5-universal-lazy-loading-on-firebase-hosting-and-seo)

Comment: Hi, you might have solved this problem now, but if not could you post the entirety of your server JS file (the one that includes the line `provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)`)? I just encountered this issue myself and managed to solve it by making sure I use `renderModuleFactory` in production mode only, and `renderModule` otherwise.

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Answer (score 13):

TLDR;

```
npm uninstall @nguniversal/common
npm uninstall @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
```

and remove `ModuleMapLoaderModule` from your `app.server.module.ts`.

TSWM;

In Angular < 9, Universal was relying on `@nguniversal/common` and `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader` to handle lazy loaded modules. With Angular 9+, they now provide out of the box the `ngExpressEngine` which handles this. All you need is `@nguniversal/express-engine` as [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-tutorial) mention.

Comment: yep! Just migrated an "old" project to Angular 10 and this worked perfectly. Might be my "search technique" but so many places with the same question (or similar SSR migration issues) and this is pretty much all you need.

Comment: It didn't work, the error persited, and how can I use the lazy loading without those modules?

Comment: After uninstalling the dependencies you must deploy your app. again by running the command 'ng build --prod && ng [ProjectName]:server:production' and 'node dist/[ProjectName]/server/main.js'(of course the last command on your server :-) ) before trying again. I must add that I upgraded yet to Angular 11

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this error when I try to add module-map-ngfactory-loader to enable lazy loading but in the new version of Angular, you don't need to manually add this module. 
String-based lazy loading syntax is not supported with Ivy and hence `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader` is no longer required.

uninstalling the module (npm uninstall "package-name" ). and removing ModuleMapLoaderModule worked for me.

[see here for detail](https://github.com/alan-agius4/universal/commit/04c1d495a79782cc5b1081cf1024a9fc653f724a)